# The parent theme is missing. Please install the "bp-default" parent theme

Tags: child-theme, buddypress

I created a child theme based on the BuddyPress's `bp-default` theme by following their [documentation](https://codex.buddypress.org/legacy/theme-development/the-bp-default-theme/building-a-buddypress-child-theme/). 
I did the same as they described on the documentation. Here is my code in style.css file-

```
/* 
Name: BuddyPress Dusk 
URI: http://example.org/themes/dusk/
Description: Dark theme for BuddyPress.
Version: 1.0
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://example.org/
Template: bp-default
Tags: buddypress, two-column, grey, dark
*/
```

But I couldn't find the child theme I made based on the bp-default theme in the Themes page (`Appearance > Themes`). Also the parent theme (bp-default) hasn't appeared in the Themes page.
Probably, BuddPress removed the direct child-theme support after activating the BuddyPress plugin.

Actually, I don't know how I can create a child theme based on the 'bp-default' theme which is located on the BuddPress plugin (`plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default`).

Comment: to create a child theme you need to use the directory name of the parent theme. e.g. if the parent theme is in `wp-content/themes/bp-defaultTest3`, you need to put `Template: bp-defaultTest3`

Comment: "the BuddyPress Theme Compatibility introduced in version 1.7 which allows for nearly all WordPress themes to run BP templates within it’s theme and child themeing or customizing your BP templates by copying them to your theme/child theme easy to accomplish!" sounds like the new way to go. Why do you want to do it the old way?

Comment: Because, some of HTML markup is inheriting from the bp-default theme. As like, the comments markup inheriting from the theme (`buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/activity/comment.php`). I couldn't override the comment markup from my theme. 
I can only override the buddypress folder from my theme. Can you tell me, how I can override the comment template from my theme?